# I can not get an element of a structure be assigned within a callback in Rust using FLTK

Tags: rust, callback, fltk

this is my calling codes.

```
let var_struc_wallet = StrucWallet {
                        StrucWalletName: String::from(" "),
                        StrucWalletUserName: String::from(" "),
                        StrucWalletUserPassword: String::from(" "),
                        StrucDateLastQuery: String::from(" "),
                        StrucWalletAPIKey: String::from(" "),
                    };
                    wallet_add_check(&mut main_win, &mut var_struc_wallet);
                    let test_wallet = var_struc_wallet.StrucWalletName;
                    if test_wallet != " " {
                        wallet_add_process(&mut main_win);
```

this is the code where I am getting the error in.

```
pub fn wallet_add_check(main_win: &mut Window, v_struc_wallet: &mut StrucWallet) {
    println!("Enter wallet_add_check");
    
    let mut btn_wall_verify = fltk::button::Button::new(220, 130, 60, 20, "Verify");
    wall_group.add(&btn_wall_verify);

    btn_wall_verify.set_callback(move |_| {
        let wallet_test: bool = false;
        let wall_name_clone = wall_name.clone();
        let wallet_test = wallet_verify(wall_name_clone.value().to_string());

        if !wallet_test {
            dialog::message(
                500,
                500,
                "This Wallet already exists in the database.  Please select another.",
            );
            wall_group.hide();
        } else {
            wall_group.hide();
            v_struc_wallet.StrucWalletName = wall_name.value().to_string();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the error I get

error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `v_struc_wallet`
--> src\main.rs:503:21
|
503 |     btn_wall_verify.set_callback(move |_| {
|                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0621`.

I am using callback in other areas with success but this one is stumping me.  If I comment out the structure the error goes away but the application does not run correctly as I do not get the entry from the callback of the button.

The call to wallet_verity does return a boolean as when I comment out the line v_struc_wallet.StrucWalletName = wall_name.value().to_string();
the debugger shows the function returns either a true or false.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can’t move a short lived reference to a static closure, which might outlive the reference (which is the case since fltk widgets are long-lived) and expect to be able to use it later. If you need to pass some reference type and you need it to be mutable, you should wrap it in a smart pointer type (Rc + RefCell or Arc + Mutex).

Comment: I have tried many things but can not figure out how using a smart pointer type in the above code will help me.  I have used smart pointers in other parts of my code so I understand what they are doing but can't seem to figure this out.  Further help is appreciated.